# data-selected on javascript not displaying selected data from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I want to display selected value from database. I already render the data from json. I'm using data-selected to display the selected value from database but it did not work. I'm new in javascript & jQuery. Hope someone can give me some light.

javascript code:

```
{
data:
  "bank",
  render: function(data, type, row){
          var selectBank =
           '<select class="custom-select form-control renderBank" id="" name="billNotes['+index+'].billingNote.bank.id" data-url="/api/finance/master/banks" data-selected="'+data.id+'">';

   renderSelect2Bank(data.id);
   return selectBank;
  }
},

function renderSelect2Bank(selectedBank){
$('select.renderBank').each(function (index) {

    var that = this;
    $(that).select2({
        width: '100%',
        placeholder: "Silah pilih",
        language: "id"
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: $(that).data('url'),
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            if(data && data !== ""){
                $.each(data, function (i, val){
                    if(selectedBank === val.id){
                        $(that).append(initAutofill(val.text, val.id, true));
                    }else{
                        $(that).append(initAutofill(val.text, val.id, false));
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
            errorCallback(xhr);
        }
    });
});
```

}

Comment: Do you want to append those to html?

Comment: yes, i wanto render the selected value to html